# Randomise jig-saw puzzle into different position?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, shuffle, scramble

I am doing a jig-saw puzzle project, trying to randomise my pieces into different position and angle. Anybody got an idea of how do i start? Currently using kineticjs v4.3.3. Any way i can do the randomising? Thanks :)

```
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

P.S : My js fiddle doesn't work and i don't know why, but here the link to my code : http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/5/

Screenshot of my project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/60ql7eo0pkyvdzl/pic%203.png

Comment: Try this for your fiddle instead, http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/7/ it loads now, but theres some other issue. Check the console :)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks :) what do you meant by my console? sorry

Comment: Ctrl+shift+i, and check the web consol!

Comment: oh okok , didnt know that can be use in jsfiddle :) thanks. do you know how to randomnise my puzzle?